# How to process Heap traces?

Tags: .net-traceprocessing

Heap traces are some of the heaviest traces ETW can capture, and would be interesting to handle that through .net-trace processing.

Is it possible currently to get this data, or is it not supported?

I only see a `UseHeapSnapshots()` which, if I understand correctly, has to do with [Heap Snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/record-heap-snapshot), not [heap data capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/enabling-heap-data-capture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we do not have any special built-in support for these events, however you can still find these events in GenericEvents (which contains all Manifested and TraceLogging events in the trace) or in ClassicEvents (which contains all Classic and WPP events), or by writing an EventConsumer (see the Extensibility section of https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2019/05/09/announcing-traceprocessor-preview-0-1-0/ for an example).

Comment: Since which Windows Version are HeapSnapshots possible? I remember that wpr supported it years ago but the support was only partial. Do I only need to install the latest WPT to a Win10 Anniversary edition and I can use periodic heap snapshots?

Comment: I know there's been support since at least the 1803 update, but I don't know how far before that.